# PHP: Create individual arrays with all the duplicates of an array

Tags: php, arrays, duplicates

I have created some arrays that contain all the duplicates of some previous arrays. For example:

```
[475] => string(9) "038231370" 
[5135] => string(9) "038231370" 
[13236] => string(9) "038231370" 
[5575]=> string(9) "038231370" 
[4357]=> string(9) "038293950" 
[10509]=> string(9) "038293950" 
[6031]=> string(10) "0038303163" 
[5529]=> string(10) "0038303163" 
[534]=> string(10) "0038303163" 
[5303] ...
```

As you can some duplicates are more than one time double. What I want to do is to create different arrays which will contain the same values and their keys.

```
function compare($array) {
    $per_array = array();
    $old_key    = NULL;
    $old_value    = NULL;
    foreach($array as $key => $value){

        if ($old_value === $value) {
            $per_array[$old_key]    = $old_value;
            $per_array[$key]        = $value;
        }   
        else {(DO SOME TESTS)unset($per_array);}


        $old_value  = $value;
        $old_key    = $key; 

    }   
}
```

but I seem to miss something. Please any help would be important.

Well one example of my expected arrays is:

> per_array(4) = { [475] => string(9) "038231370"  [5135] => string(9)
>   "038231370"  [13236] => string(9) "038231370"  [5575]=> string(9)
>   "038231370"  }
>
> per_array(3) = { [4357]=> string(9) "038293950"  [10509]=> string(9)
>   "038293950" }

and so on...

Comment: Giving an example of an initial array + result array would be helpful :)

Comment: I don't understand your question very well. What you would like to do is to remove the duplicate values from the array?

Comment: Not sure what are your input arrays. See array_intersect().

Comment: I just edited my post. @Lao I don't want to remove the duplicates, I want to run some checks before I unset my array.

Comment: I have an array of this format, as I wrote in the example, containing strings and I want the result as shown.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a simple example of

- Unique Values
- Duplicate Values wit their keys

Code

```
$a = $u = $d = array();

// Build Temp Data with duplicates
for($i = "A"; $i < "M"; $i ++) {
    $a[$i] = mt_rand(0, 3);
}

//Simple Loop
foreach ( $a as $k => $v ) {
    in_array($v, $u) ? $d[$k] = $v : $u[$k] = $v;
}

var_dump($a); // Original array
var_dump($u); // Unique
var_dump($d); // Duplicate with their keys
```

Output

```
array (size=12)
  'A' => int 0
  'B' => int 2
  'C' => int 1
  'D' => int 2
  'E' => int 3
  'F' => int 3
  'G' => int 3
  'H' => int 2
  'I' => int 3
  'J' => int 1
  'K' => int 0
  'L' => int 0

array (size=4)
  'A' => int 0
  'B' => int 2
  'C' => int 1
  'E' => int 3

array (size=8)
  'D' => int 2
  'F' => int 3
  'G' => int 3
  'H' => int 2
  'I' => int 3
  'J' => int 1
  'K' => int 0
  'L' => int 0
```

Comment: My purpose is each time to save in the array per_array(), the values of which are the same only, as I edited in the example. So  `foreach ( $a as $k => $v ) {
    in_array($v, $u) ? $d[$k] = $v : $u[$k] = $v;
} ` this is not what I need right?

Comment: What do you mean by `per_array()` ? Its not in the question

Comment: per_array is the name of an array that I use. I mean, I want to create a permanent array containing the keys of duplicates if it is easier: `per_array(4) = { 475, 5135, 13236, 5575 }`

Comment: Am working with your example .. Correct me if am wrong .. you need all duplicate arrays with their keys ?? Correct ?

Comment: If you want only the duplicate key you can have `array_keys($d)` it would return all keys of the duplicate

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/19631/discussion-between-dimitra-micha-and-baba)

Answer (score 0):

Try this code :

```
$array_count = array();

foreach ($array as $key => $arr) :
    $array_count[$arr][] = $key;
endforeach;
```

Comment: I was thinking maybe                                       `foreach($array as $key => $value){

 if ($old_value === $value){
   
   $per_array[j] = $key;
          //$per_array[$old_key]    = $old_value;
            //$per_array[$key]        = $value;
            $j++;
        }
    
       
    else {
      statements
     
 unset($per_array);
 $j = 0;`